# Embed a Blob using PDFObject

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, pdfobject

I'm using: https://pdfobject.com/

To display an embedded `pdf` file on my web app. However I cannot render a `pdf` created from a `blob`.

This is what I've tried:

```
var arrayBufferView = new Uint8Array(response.Body.data);
var file = new Blob([arrayBufferView], {
    type: response.ContentType
});
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
PDFObject.embed(url, "#my-container");
```

Gets me this result on html:

```
<div id="my-container" class="ng-scope pdfobject-container">

    <embed class="pdfobject" src="blob:http%3A//localhost%3A4000/869a8d9a-7eaa-48dd-99aa-49bf299114aa" type="application/pdf" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 100%;" internalinstanceid="88">

</div>
```

However the embed container displays nothing in my browser. I'm using  Chrome  51.0.2704.103 m

Comment: What is `response.Body.data`?

Comment: Hi thanks for the interest. `response.Body.data` is the actual byte data of the pdf file. From S3: it is a (Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream) Object data. I´m getting the file from an Amazon S3 server. I just convert it to a Uint 8 array to be able to create the blob. The blob is created fine because if I paste the url in another tab on my browser the file is downloaded and opened just fine.

Comment: Try substituting using an `<iframe>` element for an `<embed>` element

Comment: Thanks! Ive already tried that but the result is the same.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/9E5sGfMhUeIWV9yodAUd?p=preview ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try using `<iframe>` element, requesting resource as a `Blob`

html

```
<div id="my-container" class="ng-scope pdfobject-container">
    <iframe src="" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" style="overflow: auto;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// load `document` from `cache`
xhr.open("GET", "/path/to/file.pdf", true); 
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        // `blob` response
        console.log(this.response);
        var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
        document.querySelector("iframe").src = file;

    }
};
xhr.send();
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/9E5sGfMhUeIWV9yodAUd?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I´m getting no display on the iframe. However the document is downloading on the iframe. Somehow the src is telling the iframe to download the file instead of rendering it. Do you know what I might be doing wrong? Also. I´m putting on 'path/to/file' the url I create from the blob i.e the result of  `window.URL.createObjectURL(file)`. Is this correct?

Comment: I also noticed this message on my console right now: `index.controller.js:202 Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "blob:http%3A//localhost%3A4000/05f21b69-b7ad-4615-8ece-afa142afa440".`

Comment: @PabloEstrada Tried using same approach at  `html`, `javascript` at post? Can you fork plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/9E5sGfMhUeIWV9yodAUd?p=preview to demonstrate?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was my fault. I had incorrect header on the content-type. I changed them to application/pdf and it render correctly know. Thanks!

Comment: @JayShukla Which version of ie?

Answer (score 3):

Just a complement to the answer by using iframe, we need also to use pdfjs viewer on this otherwise it will download.

```
<div id="my-container" class="PDFObject-container">
    <iframe src="/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file=blob:http://xxx:8098/fsadfsaf" type="application/pdf" width="1000" height="600" style="overflow: auto;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

The blob is created from binary response creates with Javascript

```
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response], { type: 'application/pdf' }));
```

I do hope PDFObject can do the work without using iframe but as tested, it's not success.

Answer (score 1):

This is what l believe you were looking for.

```
function previewPdf(billName) {

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'home/download?pdfBillId=' + billName, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.status == 200) {
        var file = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        var viewer = $('#viewpdf');
        PDFObject.embed(fileURL, viewer);
    }
};
xhr.send(); 
}
```

Comment: did similar here but not working `PDFObject.embed(val, vm.$el, options);`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
 var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

Try using:

```
 var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file, { type: 'application/pdf' })
```