# Displaying pdf from arraybuffer

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, dompdf

I am returning stream data from laravel dompdf from this code

```
 $pdf = \App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
 $pdf->loadHTML("<div>This is test</div>");
 return $pdf->stream();
```

And this is my JS ajax code

```
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "/display",
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).done(function( response ) {
        var blob = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var pdfurl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)+"#view=FitW";
        $("#pdfviewer").attr("data",pdfurl);
    });
```

Here is HTML to display pdf after ajax

```
<object id="pdfviewer" data="/files/sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></object>
```

I am getting below error

> Failed to load PDF document

Please help to fix this. How to display pdf file.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`jQuery.ajax()` does not have a `responseType` setting by default. You can use a polyfill, for example [jquery-ajax-blob-arraybuffer.js](https://gist.github.com/SaneMethod/7548768) which implements binary data transport, or utilize `fetch()`.

Note also, chrome, chromium have issues displaying `.pdf` at either `<object>` and `<embed>` elements, see [Displaying PDF using object embed tag with blob URL](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=569888), [Embed a Blob using PDFObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031229/embed-a-blob-using-pdfobject/38031697#38031697). Substitute using `<iframe>` element for `<object>` element.

```
$(function() {

  var pdfsrc = "/display";

  var jQueryAjaxBlobArrayBuffer = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SaneMethod/" 
                         + "7548768/raw/ae22b1fa2e6f56ae6c87ad0d7fbae8fd511e781f/" 
                         + "jquery-ajax-blob-arraybuffer.js";

  var script = $("<script>");

  $.get(jQueryAjaxBlobArrayBuffer)
  .then(function(data) {
    script.text(data).appendTo("body")
  }, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .then(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: pdfsrc,
      dataType: "arraybuffer"
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      // do stuff with `data`
      console.log(data, data instanceof ArrayBuffer);
      $("#pdfviewer").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
            type: "application/pdf"
          })))
     }, function(err) {
          console.log(err);
     });

  });
});
```

Using `fetch()`, `.arrayBuffer()`

```
  var pdfsrc = "/display";

  fetch(pdfsrc)
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.arrayBuffer()
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    // do stuff with `data`
    console.log(data, data instanceof ArrayBuffer);
    $("#pdfviewer").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
        type: "application/pdf"
    })))
  }, function(err) {
      console.log(err);
  });
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/9R5WcsMSWQaTbgNdY3RJ?p=preview

version 1 `jquery-ajax-blob-arraybuffer.js`, `jQuery.ajax()`; version 2 `fetch()`, `.arrayBuffer()`

Comment: This is pretty good, but note that it won't let you name the PDF file.

Comment: @mlissner What do you mean by "name the PDF file"?

Comment: When you go to download it, you'll get the blob URL, not the name of the file.

Comment: @mlissner  Downloading a file is not relevant to the current Question.  `download` attribute value at `<a>` element only provides a suggestion for the file name at offer of file for download. The file can be renamed  at `Save File` prompt or at local filesystem after downloading the file. See [How to build PDF file from binary string returned from a web-service using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876000/how-to-build-pdf-file-from-binary-string-returned-from-a-web-service-using-javas) for question and answers relating to downloading a file.

Comment: But if you create an `object` or an `iframe` with a blob URL for the src attribute it'll have a messed up filename if you try to download it. The Q&A you link to is a pretty good solution for that (thank you!), but this answer, above, does create an issue with the name of the file if you choose to download it. Doesn't it?

Answer (score 5):

I like [guest271314](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42195304/2361449) answer a lot, especially the second version using fetch, but I wanted to add a solution that does not use a polyfill or an experimental technology like `fetch`.

This solution uses the native [XMLHttpRequest API](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to create the request. This allows us to change the `responseType` to `arrayBuffer`.

```
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var pdfsrc = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/62/Definition_of_management.pdf";
  xhr.open('GET', pdfsrc, true);
  xhr.responseType = "arraybuffer";

  xhr.addEventListener("load", function (evt) {
    var data = evt.target.response;
    if (this.status === 200) {
      $("#pdfviewer").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
        type: "application/pdf"
      })));
    }
  }, false);

  xhr.send();
```

I forked guest271314s plnkr to show this method in action:
http://plnkr.co/edit/7tfBYQQdnih9cW98HSXX?p=preview

Answer (score 3):

From my tests the responce is in response not response.data, so the following should work:

```
  $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "/display",
        responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    }).done(function( response ) {
        var blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
        var pdfurl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)+"#view=FitW";
        $("#pdfviewer").attr("data",pdfurl);
    });
```

Although it seems JQuery is doing something with the responce causing a blank PDF output... ([PDF is blank when downloading using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436133/pdf-is-blank-when-downloading-using-javascript)). This will work:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'test.pdf', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
   if (this.status == 200) {
        var blob=new Blob([this.response], {type:"application/pdf"});
        var pdfurl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)+"#view=FitW";
        $("#pdfviewer").attr("data",pdfurl);
   }
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: after changing `response.data` to `response` I am getting completely blank pdf. no output. I think we are near to fix this, may be need to change in `responseType` or `Content-type` any where.

Comment: @AndrewMonks _"From my tests the responce is in response not response.data, so the following should work"_ Can you share  tests at a stacksnippets, jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net, or plnkr http://plnkr.co ?

Comment: unfortunately not as you cannot upload a pdf file to a snippet site and CORs blocks requests to other sites PDF files. Allthough see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34436133/pdf-is-blank-when-downloading-using-javascript I checked again and was getting a blank output. Try using a raw XMLHttpRequest instead of jquery and it will work.

Comment: @AndrewMonks `jQuery.ajax()` does not have a `responseType` setting by default.