# How to preview PDf file in AngularJS application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to preview a pdf document inside AngularJS app.

From my Web API, I am sending as bytes

```
[Route("PdfData")]
        [HttpGet]
        public byte[] GetPdfData()
        {
            BlobService bs = new BlobService();
            var blobPdfContent = bs.PdfRecordsInBytes("Sample.pdf");
            return blobPdfContent;
        }
```

My angularJS code is as under

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">


        <embed ng-src="{{content}}" style="width:200px;height:200px;"></embed>

    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', [ '$scope', '$sce','$http',function($scope,$sce,$http) {

            $http.get("http://localhost:67845/PdfData")
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);                     
                    $scope.content = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(response.data);
                }); }]);
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

In the console, i am able to find the byte data  but nothing is previewed.... what is that i am missing?

**console**

[image]

**But browser**

[image]

Comment: If possible, set response type of `$http.get()` to `"arraybuffer"` or `"blob"`, use `<iframe>` element to display `.pdf`, see [Displaying pdf from arraybuffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106584/displaying-pdf-from-arraybuffer/)

Comment: See also [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata/)

Comment: @guest271314, as per your advice, i have tried var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      console.log(response.data);          
          $scope.content = blob;    but no luck..pls help

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar can you post `response.data` so that I will use that.

Comment: Set response type of request to `"blob"`, you can then pass the resulting `Blob` to `URL.createObjectURL()` to set at `<iframe>` `.src`. Have you tried the Answers at linked Question?

Comment: @Saurabh Agrawal, how you want me to send? It's a huge chunk to post here

Comment: Response appears to be `base64` encoded string. You can use approaches at linked Question to convert `base64` string to `Blob`. Have you checked documentation of `$http.get()` to determine is a `.responseType` can be set for the request?

Comment: @guest271314, brilliant catch..... i got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where `MIME` type of `base64` string is known, as demonstrated by @Endless at [Convert Data URI to File then append to FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998908/convert-data-uri-to-file-then-append-to-formdata/), you can pass `data URI` to `fetch()` call return `Response.blob()` from chained `.then()` to covert `base64` encoded  to `Blob`. Set `<iframe>` element `.src` to `Blob URL` of file object returned from `URL.createObjectURL()` to display `.pdf` at `html` `document`.

```
let pdf = "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";

fetch(`data:application/pdf;base64,${pdf}`)
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => document.querySelector("iframe").src = URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/WrKRF1hKnN36LZ8e6m11?p=preview

See also [Displaying pdf from arraybuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106584/displaying-pdf-from-arraybuffer/)