# How to display a jpeg as the source attribute of an IMG tag, returned by a PHP file, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, image

I have to admit, that as a neophyte, I don't even properly know how to ask my question. Here goes though.

Context:
I have a registration script written in PHP which uses a security code generating PHP script, which generates a jpeg which is loaded directly as an image, containing the graphical representation of a randomly generated string, which is stored in a cookie and has to be entered by the registering party in order to validate the registration form.

Goal:
I want to create my own "refresh" code which would call upon the security code generating script to create and display a new security image each time I press the "Refresh" button.

Here is the security code generating script:

```
<?php

$im = imagecreate(300,60) or die("Cannot initialize new GD Image stream"); // identyfikator zasobu
$backgroundcolor = imagecolorallocate( $im, 225, 225, 225 );
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate( $im, 0, 0, 0 );
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 140, 30, $backgroundcolor);


if( isset($_POST['refresh']) )
{
    if( isset($_COOKIE['randomimage']) )
        unset($_COOKIE['randomimage']);

    $randomizedString = createRandomString();
    imagestring( $im, 100, 65, 20, $randomizedString, $textcolor );
    setcookie('randomimage', $randomizedString, time() + 270 );
}
else if ( !isset($_COOKIE['randomimage'] ) )
{
    $randomizedString = createRandomString();
    imagestring( $im, 100, 65, 20, $randomizedString, $textcolor );

    setcookie('randomimage', $randomizedString, time() + 270 );
}
else
{
    $image_string = $_COOKIE['randomimage'];
    imagestring( $im, 100, 65, 20, $image_string, $textcolor );


}

header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);


function createRandomString()
{
    srand( (double) microtime() * 1000000 );

    $letters_capital = range('A', 'Z');
    $letters_small = range('a', 'z');
    $number = range(0,9);

    $chars = array_merge($letters_capital, $number, $letters_small );

    shuffle($chars);

    $randString = "";

    for ( $i = 0; $i < 10; $i++ )
    {
        $randString .= $chars[$i] . " ";
    }

    return $randString;
}
```

?>

Here is the jQuery code, part of the registration script:

```
$('#refreshBtn').on('click', function(event){
        $.post(
            "./createrandomizedimaged83r04.php",           // action
            {                                   // data
               refresh: "refresh"
            },
            function(data)                      // callback
            {


                $('#imgPic2').attr('src',data);


            }
        );

    });
```

The result appears in the firefox console as follows:

```
GET http://***directory***/%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD
```

At this point, I suspect, though I probably am not using the correct terminology, that I'm trying to push some kind of binary representation of the image into the img's src, which results in gibberish.

If instead, inside the jQuery portion I write the following:

```
$('#imgPic').html('<img src=\'' + data +'\'>');
```

I am served with the following:

```
�����Yy?j��:U�/6@�d��.z������O����0������3��7��ե\��|C-���D y�]�h-ؑ)��#��ŏʼ��~����4�m���*���,��*H��ޭ�7��=�4� Y����w���p�;���8Pp0���rN���Ѵ{8�������A{�_qh�1�}��'�cg{i�ڥՕ�76�gd�Hpy~��� '�T����H�U�I�;מ�nSa�R�J�Ҧ�t� ^I�����%�UcvU���gnH�kѨxj�x���:L�J�#�;�ٝ���$�����/�%Oǿ��� ]�e^x���u����e��x��q��FFA9կ<���д_�h���b������Z�&���e�@.0W 79����Q_�kJ���-!��c��bV@B0�AӥiQ\W����|k�#N՞� YgI��9~HY7&��nO�r�s�"�}*������5� �c��X��'*��f7��Ǩ�(�� (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� (�� ������mt�4�Ta|�Wluc��y�袀3uh���>�����*�\�$�$�, �I�ޯAV�G$Pġ#�5 ��`ڤ�� �����~�m�L�4^la��G\�a��9��V�o�١�g�����g�����ny�L��Ps��A
```

How on Earth do I take the image which is passed by the PHP code-generating script and use jQuery to display it?

Here's where the image is supposed to go (inside the registration script):

```
<table align='left' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='4' width='100%'>
<tr>
    <td align='center' colspan='2' id='imgPic' name='imgPic'><img id='imgPic2' src='{$this->image_url}'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='center' colspan='2' id='refreshBtn' name='refreshBtn'><input id='refreshBtn' name='refreshBtn' type='button' class='button' value='Refresh'></td>
</tr>
<tr align='center'>
    <td align='right' style='width:50%;'><span class='registration'><font style='color:#663300;'>Enter the above phrase:</font></span></td>
    <td align='left' style='width:50%;'><input type='text' id='wordVal' name='wordVal' autocompelte='off' maxlength='10' size='17'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align='center' colspan='2'><span id='orgWord'></span>
    <br>
    <span id='usrWord'></span></td>
</tr>
```

Please help me with the code. Also, since the jQuery code (inside the registration script) makes a POST request to the code-generating script, I'd like to know how to set the refreshed image using a POST request, instead of GET.

Regards and thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Use a `data-url`

Comment: May I ask why the *post* requirement?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown apparently it will be used like a captcha for form verification.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir exactly, it's a captcha-type of verification, but how should I use data-url?

Comment: @michalinator See the second part of DontVoteMeDown's answer, it talks about the data-url.

Comment: @michalinator This could help too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915058/how-to-display-binary-data-as-image-extjs-4

Answer (score 3):

If the `content-type` is of image type itself, no need to open an ajax request:

```
$('#refreshBtn').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#imgPic').attr('src', './createrandomizedimaged83r04.php?_=' + (new Date()).getTime());
});
```

However, this isn't a post request, since `img` tag opens a get request by default.

---

If you really need doing this by a post request, I suggest you to use an ajax request expecting a *base64* content.

Make your PHP script to result in a base64 image(check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758760/1267304)) and use the result as the image's `src` attribute, just like you're doing in your javascript.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir it refreshes the image if your *change* the url to the same one?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I have tested, what you proposed works.

Comment: Yeah! I was about to myself. But I just realized it may not be a 100% reliable because of caching...

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir just add a timestamp after the url and bye bye cache.

Comment: You could just change the `src` of the image instead of removing the element every time. Just append a random number in the query string so the browser won't "cache" it.

Comment: @gforce301 yeah, just realized it.

Comment: He should prefix it with a `data:image/jpeg;base64,`.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir sure, as said in the post I've linked.

Comment: I'm going to use data:image/jpeg;base64, I've seen some code concerning this, might work, as for avoiding cache with timestamps, I imagine I'd have to pass the time stamp as an argument in the jQuery POST request.

Comment: @michalinator or you can add `cache:false` and jQuery will do it for you.

Comment: Where do I place cache:false (I'm a bit green so far).

Comment: @michalinator you would have to use `$.ajax` instead of `$.post` for that, then you could change some settings. `$.post` is a shorthand for `$.ajax` with some default settings. If you like to know how [check this](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jQuery-post-settings)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `XMLHttpRequest()` or `fetch()` to `POST` data to server and get response from server as a `Blob` or `ArrayBuffer`, which can be converted to `Blob URL` or `data URI` using `FileReader` or `Response` then set result as `.src` of `<img>` element.

`jQuery.ajax()` and `jQuery.post()` does not have default option of setting `.responseType` to `"blob"` or `"arraybuffer"`; or calling `.blob()` or `.arrayBuffer()`, see [Displaying pdf from arraybuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106584/displaying-pdf-from-arraybuffer/42195304#42195304).

```
let url;

$('#refreshBtn').on('click', function(event) {
  if (url) {
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  }
  var fd = new FormData();
  fd.append("request", "request");
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("POST", "./createrandomizedimaged83r04.php", true);
  request.responseType = "blob";
  request.onload = function() {     
                     url = URL.createObjectURL(this.response);           
                     $('#imgPic2').attr('src', url);
                   }
  request.onerror = function(e) {
                      console.log(e, this.responseText)
                    }
  request.send(fd);

});
```

Comment: I'm definitely going to try this, can't right now. I will get back to you. I'm going to have to look into the "let" keyword, as I don't know what its function is.

Comment: I like this solution, but I think a little more complex than using base64.

Comment: See [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown A `data URL` could be substituted as return value at `php` and set at `.src` of `<img>` element. Approach at Answer should not require adjusting existing `php` code.

Comment: @michalinator If the same key, value pair is passed at each `POST` request, a new `FormData` instance does not need to be created at each `click` event, you can define the `FormData` object outside scope of `click` event.

Comment: I just finished trying it, found time. Unfortunately it does nothing on my end; no errors, no effect - not even if I reload the page after pressing the refresh button.

Comment: @michalinator _"it does nothing"_ What does log print at server for request? What is `this.response` at `XMLHttpRequest()` `load` event? Is `<input id='refreshBtn' name='refreshBtn' type='button' class='button' value='Refresh'>` child node of a `<form>` element?

Comment: @michalinator Is `<input id='refreshBtn' name='refreshBtn' type='button' class='button' value='Refresh'>` appended to `document` dynamically?

Comment: Actually, it seems to be generating the same picture. I'm going to review my code generating script.

The response type of this.response is [object Blob] 

N.B.: Obtained via alert(this.response).

Comment: Where do you generate a different image for each request at `php`? Yes, the expected response is a `Blob` object, which is not a string

Comment: Couldn’t edit my previous comment any longer, so here is the revised version:

Actually, it seems to be generating the same picture for the given cookie's time frame of 270s seconds. When the time-frame expires, it successfully loads the new picture. I'm going to review my code generating script.

The response type of this.response is [object Blob] 

N.B.: Obtained via alert(this.response).

Comment: `this.response` is expected to be `Blob` object at `javascript`.  _"Actually, it seems to be generating the same picture for the given cookie's time frame of 270s seconds. When the time-frame expires, it successfully loads the new picture. I'm going to review my code generating script. "_ What is expected result?

Comment: Solved! I googled the .append() function of form data - I didn't know but suspected that it was a key-value type of function which added such pairs to a form request. Since the original code consisted of:

fd.append("request","request");

I replaced it to read:

fd.append('refresh','refresh');

Ta-dah! Your original code loaded the picture just fine, thanks for the help.

P.S.: I'm going to review everyone's answers to collect as much information as possible.