# MemoryStream to HttpResponseMessage

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf

I have generated a Pdf on the server, and need to return it as a response to my web client, so that I get a 'Save As' dialog.

The pdf is generated, and saved to a Memory stream... which is then returned to my method which will return the HttpResponseMessage.

The is the method:

```
[Route("GeneratePdf"), HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage GeneratePdf(PlateTemplateExtendedDto data)
{

    var doc = GeneratePdf(DataForThePdf);

    //using (var file = File.OpenWrite("c:\\temp\\test.pdf"))
    //    doc.CopyTo(file); // no need for manual stream copy and buffers

    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
    //get buffer
    buffer = doc.GetBuffer();
    //content length for use in header
    var contentLength = buffer.Length;

    response.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response.Content = new StreamContent(doc);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("render");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "yes.pdf";
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = doc.Length;

    return response;
}
```

However, the document renders as a blank file, and although it has a file size, and properties of the document I created (pdf information if File Properties is all right, as well as page width and height), the document displays as blank.

If I un-comment the code that is commented out, to save locally, the file is perfect. File size is 228,889 bytes. However, when I let it go to my web page and save it, it's 405,153 bytes and the filename is 'undefined'.

If I breakpoint, I see these results:

[image]

On the front end script, I handle the downloaded object like this:

```
$.post("/api/PlateTemplate/GeneratePdf", data).done(function (data, status, headers) {

            // headers = headers();

            var filename = headers['x-filename'];
            var contentType = headers['content-type'];
            //Create a url to the blob
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: contentType });
            var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var linkElement = document.createElement('a');
            linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
            linkElement.setAttribute("download", filename);

            //Force a download
            var clickEvent = new MouseEvent("click", {
                "view": window,
                "bubbles": true,
                "cancelable": false
            });
            linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
        });
```

I'm unsure where the file is being corrupted. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Using the following code as suggested:

```
$.post("/api/PlateTemplate/GeneratePdf", data).done(function (data, status, headers) {
            alert(data.length);

            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            $("#pdfviewer").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
                type: "application/pdf"
            })))
```

.Net code:

```
var doc = GeneratePdf(pdfParams);

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[0];
            //get buffer
            buffer = doc.ToArray();
            //content length for use in header
            var contentLength = buffer.Length;

            response.Headers.AcceptRanges.Add("bytes");
            response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            response.Content = new StreamContent(doc);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("render");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "yes.pdf";
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = doc.Length;

            return response;
```

It seems I am losing data.
The alert is the length of the 'data.length' in my javascript, after I get data back from the call.
The file properties is the original pdf file info.

[image]

File sends from api, size is 227,564, which matches the byte size on disk if I save it. So it SEEMS the sending is OK. But on the javascript size, when I read in the file, it's 424946, when I do: var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' }); (Where data is the response from the server).

Comment: use `doc.ToArray()` not `doc.GetBuffer()`

Comment: jQuery ajax does not process binary data by default  [Displaying pdf from arraybuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106584/displaying-pdf-from-arraybuffer), see also [How to build PDF file from binary string returned from a web-service using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876000/how-to-build-pdf-file-from-binary-string-returned-from-a-web-service-using-javas/)

Comment: @L.B and Guest - I've tried both your ideas, and edited my question. It seems I am losing some data somewhere.... The PDF is trying to render, but I am short on bytes, so the file seems to be trunacted somehow? I've added the details to the end of the question.

Comment: Tried all the things you guys have said plus more. File sends from api, size is 227,564, which matches the byte size on disk if I save it. So it SEEMS the sending is OK. But on the javascript size, when I read in the file, it's 424946, when I do: var file = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/pdf' }); (Where data is the response from the server).

Comment: Craig's post is not using jquery ajax - it is using a created linkElement to download it. I am having this same problem. I try to download the link to my Web Api Controller Action and it looks good until I look at the file that was downloaded - it is zero bytes. There must be something wrong with the way the response.Content was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I 'fixed' this by using base64 encoded string from the .Net controller to the javascript web api call result, and then allowed the browser to convert it into binary by specifying the type ('application/pdf').

Answer (score 0):

The ContentLength setting looks somewhat suspicious (not consequent):

```
       //content length for use in header
        var contentLength = buffer.Length;
        response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = doc.Length;
```

Comment: I changed doc.Length to contentLength, but am getting same results. size difference is different, but still smaller than it should be.

Answer (score 0):

*I think your problem shows a bug somewhere in Microsoft's MemoryStream or perhaps HttpResponseMessage or some related library.* **By searching for this and other topics I came up with this stupid fix workaround for this (not ideal):**

(stream was my returned MemoryStream variable from a fct returning a pdf file into a MemoryStream from our code to create a pdf file using Aspose. I got pieces of this and that from other web articles or stackoverflow posts, etc.):

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyPDFExportReport(string fromDate, string toDate)
{

MemoryStream stream = MyCreatePDFReport(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/MyFolder/Aspose.Total.lic"), fromDate, toDate);
pdfFileName = "C:\MyFileName.Pdf";

var fileStream = File.Create(pdfFileName);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
fileStream.Close();

var filestream2 = File.OpenRead(pdfFileName);
filestream2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { Private = true, MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10) };
response.Content = new StreamContent(filestream2); 
response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = filestream2.Length;
response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = filename };
return response;
}
```

I know this is a stupid fix - it is what it is. I tried creating a new MemoryStream and using Stream.CopyTo(newMemoryStream) and close and seek on that - did not work.

I may also try reading my original MemoryStream into a large array and then passing that in somehow to the response.Content.

Answer (score 0):

**I found a better solution than what I previously submitted:**

(stream was my returned MemoryStream variable from a fct returning a pdf file into a MemoryStream from our code to create a pdf file using Aspose. I got pieces of this and that from other web articles or stackoverflow posts, etc.):

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyPDFExportReport(string fromDate, string toDate)
{
  MemoryStream stream = MyCreatePDFReport(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/MyFolder/Aspose.Total.lic"), fromDate, toDate);
  Stream stream2 = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray()); //This fixes the zero length PDF file problem.

  HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
  response.Headers.CacheControl = new CacheControlHeaderValue() { Private = true, MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10) };
  response.Content = new StreamContent(stream2); 
  response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
  response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream2.Length;
  response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileName = filename };
  return response;
}
```