# HttpResponseMessage always empty if using MemoryStream instead of FileStream

Tags: stream, httpresponse, asp.net-apicontroller

I want to create a HttpResponse that streams a local file.
I want to use a MemoryStream, so that I can delete the file afterwards (well actually before returning the repsonse).
I always end up with an empty response although the stream seems to be valid.
Working with a FileStream in API Controller works, though.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetExcelFile(Guid id)
        {
            // this model is needed to internally create an .xls file that represents this model
            var exportModel = this.myService.GetExport(id);

            // this approach does not work -> respone always empty although memory stream has content
            // var stream = new MemoryStream();
            // internally creates a .xls file (using lib) and returns its content as memory stream
            // this.myService.ConvertToStream(exportModel, stream));

            // this works fine
            var stream = File.OpenRead(@"D:\test0815.xls");

            var result = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

            result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            result.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
            result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                                                            {
                                                                FileName = $"{exportModel.Name}-Sheet.xls"
                                                            };

            return result;
        }
```

this is my method that actually converts to memorystream:

```
 private MemoryStream SaveToStream(MemoryStream stream)
        {
            using (FileStream source = File.Open(
                @"D:\test0815.xls",
                FileMode.Open))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source length: {0}", source.Length.ToString());

                // Copy source to destination.

                source.CopyTo(stream);
            }

            return stream;
        }
```

I also tried writing to memory stream but this did not work either.
It seems that `result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);` is just not working with an memory stream.

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

finally I found a working solution:

```
  var memoryStream = new MemoryStream((int)fileStream.Length);
            fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            fileStream.Close();
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            HttpContent content = new StreamContent(memoryStream);

            var result = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
            result.Content =content;
            result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
```

Comment: I tried your solution - did not help. But I eventually "stumbled" on this stupid work around: if you save the MemoryStream to a file, then read the memorystream back into a  new filestream then you can set the result.Content = that new filestream and that fixes the problem. This seems like a bug in MemoryStream or HttpResponseMessage or other.

Comment: Are you using Aspose? I found a solution. Here is the link to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45124013/memorystream-to-httpresponsemessage/77705657#77705657