# Base64 PDF in new tab shows Blank Page before Refresh

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, chromium, data-url

The title says it all really... I have a base64 pdf string which I append to:
`data:application/pdf;base64,`

The pdf is brought into a new tab using a link in my webpage. A blank page will initially show up, but then I refresh the page and it displays perfectly.

This issue only began once I changed my NodeJS code for retreiving the PDF, before it was retreiving the PDF with the `https` module but now I am using `request`.

https://jsfiddle.net/o7upp4d8/

Comment: No actual question appears at OP? Can you post `base64` string at jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net or plnkr https://plnkr.co?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pdf.js: rendering a pdf file using a base64 file source instead of url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12092633/pdf-js-rendering-a-pdf-file-using-a-base64-file-source-instead-of-url)

Comment: @guest271314 I added a jsfiddle.

Comment: The `data URI` is malformed. How the `data URI` created?

Comment: Well I get the `data URI` from the USPS Webtools API. Then I throw it straight into the webpage in a link like so: `href="data:application/pdf;base64,<?php echo $label; ?>"` and it was just working until I changed my method for retrieval of the URI.

Comment: @guest271314 I just checked the console on that link and found this: `Not allowed to navigate top frame to data URL`, that then lead me here: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM

Comment: @MichaelAdair So they have already began the madness https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/d/msg/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM/b3wXkW6JAgAJ. Try using an `<iframe>` to render the `.pdf` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106584/displaying-pdf-from-arraybuffer/

Comment: @guest271314 Thanks for your help... this changes a lot.

Comment: @ObsidianAge No, the present Question is not a duplicate of the linked Question. It is a new "feature" of browser behaviour, see link at previous comment

Comment: @MichaelAdair Yes, it does change the landscape. At this point probably time to build a version of chromium without the "feature", though if you read the thread it appears that there is push to implement the "feature" at each of the browsers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a current push to disallow new `window`s to have the ability to navigate to a `data URL` [Intent to Deprecate and Remove: Top-frame navigations to data URLs](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!msg/blink-dev/GbVcuwg_QjM/b3wXkW6JAgAJ). The "feature" is apparently already being implemented.

There was some objection raised to the idea, but apparently not enough; at least not yet.