# Base64 encoded to pdf in Google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, base64

How can we display a PDF using JavaScript from a base64 in Google chrome?
As application:PDF,base64:pdfbase64binary is not working anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Blob URL` to represent the file.

```
fetch(<data URI>)
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
  // do stuff with `Blob URL`
  const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

See [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript/), also 
[Base64 PDF in new tab shows Blank Page before Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45558645/base64-pdf-in-new-tab-shows-blank-page-before-refresh/).

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open("data:application/octet-stream;base64," + response)
```