# How can I construct a jQuery getScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, github, getscript, construct

I've made a JavaScript code that is way to big for easy copy-paste. Therefore, it would be perfect to use jQuery's getScript to make it smaller.

I'm having a hard time to get it to work. I tought it maybe could be some spesial way to construct the .js. Here is what I got so far trying to figure it out.

```
javascript: 
(function() {
$.getScript("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stianteien/forsvarsoversikt/master/test.js"); 
})()
```

Directed to this page: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stianteien/forsvarsoversikt/master/test.js
With the simple code:

```
alert("hello");
```

...my browser is sending an error:

> Loading fail for this `<script>` with this source

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub serves `.js` files as plain text. You can use `$.get()` or `$.ajax()`, create a `<script>` element and set the `.textContent` of the `<script>` element to the response, then append the `<script>` element to the `document` see [Displaying pdf from arraybuffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106584/displaying-pdf-from-arraybuffer/)

Comment: Thanks!
But I don't think it's the whole answer that I'm looking for. 

I want to run my github-script on any page.