# Save a PDF as ByteArray to HttpResponse using PDFDocument.Save

Tags: c#, pdf, html-to-pdf

I am trying to send a **`Byte Array`** of Conversion - HTML to PDF using `SelectPDF` in C#. The Sample code I given below. I'm having a WebAPI, in that I'm doing this. I need to send the PDF document as an byte array and need to display in the client UI. The following code is not performing.

Refer documentation of SelectPDF https://selectpdf.com/docs/M_SelectPdf_PdfDocument_Save_3.htm

```
string html = "<html><body>hello world</body></html>";
PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html, "");
doc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response, true, "C:\MyProject\Pdf\Sample.pdf");
```

If I make the API return type as `HttpResponseMessage`, then its working, instead of returning the HttpContext.Current.Response (Return type is HttpResponse), its not working.

Working code

Saving the pdf to local using the following code `doc.Save(URL)` and then need to read the file ([C# 4.0: Convert pdf to byte[] and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451864/c-sharp-4-0-convert-pdf-to-byte-and-vice-versa))

Kindly assist me how to return the Response using `doc.Save(HttpContext.Current.Response, true, "C:\MyProject\Pdf\Sample.pdf");`

> Note: Kindly provide the solution without saving the file in local
>   (i.e., Server Local)

Working C# Code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetSamplePDF() {
    string html = "<html><body>hello world</body></html>";
    PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertHtmlString(html, "");
    doc.Save("C:\MyProject\Pdf\Sample.pdf");

    pdfData = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\MyProject\Pdf\Sample.pdf");

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK) {
                Content = new ByteArrayContent(reportdata)
            };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition =
                new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {
                    FileName = "SamplePDF"
                };
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

   return result;
}
```

Moreover the UI code is [Embed a Blob using PDFObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031229/embed-a-blob-using-pdfobject)

Comment: What's the signature of `PDFDocument.Save()`? Does it accept a `Stream`? If so, it's likely that the `Stream` was meant for input, not output. But I'm not familiar with that one, I've used iText.

Comment: @GlennFerrie - Kindly refer the link https://selectpdf.com/docs/M_SelectPdf_PdfDocument_Save_3.htm

Comment: `If I make the API return type as HttpResponseMessage, then its working, instead of returning the HttpContext.Current.Response (Return type is HttpResponse), its not working.` Please show us the exact code that **is** working, and the exact code that **isn't** working.

Comment: Got it. Your problem is that the last argument should be a filename, i.e. Sample.pdf.  It's the filename when you download. — You shouldn't pass a full path. Forget my earlier comment regarding `Stream`

Comment: @GlennFerrie - I updated the question. Kindly refer the question it contains the working code.

Comment: Is  there a way to do this without storing the pdf?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming to this via a search engine.  All you need to do is not pass an overload and it returns a `byte[]`.

```
doc.Save();
```