# How can we open a pdf file inside an angular application which was already uploaded to the same angular application

Tags: javascript, angular, pdf-viewer

I am developing an angular application in which I uploaded a pdf file. I need to open the same pdf file onClick of it inside same application in a modalwindow.
I tried using  and  but no use. I should not use any pdf-viewers

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can just re-use your uploaded pdf like blob and open it in a new Tab:

```
var blob = new Blob([pdfBuffer], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(blobURL);
```

If you don't want to open it in a new tab, you need to find a Plugin to display blob inside your html. Or maybe with iframe.

Try using  element, requesting resource as a Blob

html

```
<div id="my-container" class="ng-scope pdfobject-container">
    <iframe src="" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%" style="overflow: auto;">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

javascript

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
// load `document` from `cache`
xhr.open("GET", "/path/to/file.pdf", true); 
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function (e) {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        // `blob` response
        console.log(this.response);
        var file = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
        document.querySelector("iframe").src = file;

    }
};
xhr.send();
```

-> Also see
[Embed a Blob using PDFObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38031229/embed-a-blob-using-pdfobject)